# Вытащить число из базы данных

Tags: java, mysql

В базе имеется столбец number, тип данных NUMERIC, необходимо вытащить число из этого столбца, прибавить к нему другое число и записать обратно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прибавляется константа, не зависящая от предыдущего значения `number` — проще всего одним запросом вида «`UPDATE ... SET "number" = "number" + ?`»